# Attach sentiment to each word from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I did a sentiment analysis of tweets but now I have to attach the sentiment to each word from the tweet text. My sentiment analysis was based on a sum of words that appeared in a dictionary. I hope this example can help you.

I tried to use this function but it does not work here.

```
def append_sentiment(sentences, sentiment):
return [(word, sentiment) for sentence in sentences
                          for word in sentence.split()]

append_sentiment(df['text'], df['score'])
```

Example:

```
id | text | score

12 | I like this | 2
```

Wanted result:

```
id | text | score

12 | ('I', 2), ('like', 2), ('this', 2) | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct `(word, sentiment)` tuples easily with the use of [`itertools.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat):

```
from itertools import repeat

mapped = df.apply(lambda row: list(zip(row.text.split(), repeat(row.score))), axis=1)
print(mapped)
0    [(I, 2), (like, 2), (this, 2)]
```